# While creating user in Odoo getting operation cannot be completed

Tags: odoo, createuser, odoo-14

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am getting the below error while creating a user in Odoo, initially, it was working fine but suddenly it started showing this error:

> The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record
> being deleted. If possible, archive it instead.
>
> Model: Unknown (Unknown), Constraint:
> digest_digest_res_users_rel_digest_digest_id_fkey

Please provide me help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have installed, uninstalled module on the database and it stored constraint in the table. So if we drop that constraint, system will work smoothly.

You may try with this:

- Login in your postgresql database.
- Copy this query `alter table digest_digest drop constraint` and press tab and check if you find above `digest_digest_res_users_rel_digest_digest_id_fkey` constraint.

Comment: Though i was already about to delete it but wasn't sure and didn't. got courage :D, thank you for your help

Comment: Bounty given :)